# how to reduce tertiary conditionals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, conditional-statements, code-cleanup

So I have this code which works perfectly, it's just that it looks ugly and takes up alot of space. is there a way to reduce the amount of lines this code takes? Code here:

> ```
> radius:
>       Platform.OS === 'android'
>         ? showMore === 1
>           ? androidRadius * 2
>           : showMore === 2
>           ? androidRadius * 4
>           : showMore === 3
>           ? androidRadius * 10
>           : showMore === 4
>           ? androidRadius * 25
>           : showMore === 5
>           ? androidRadius * 50
>           : showMore === 6
>           ? androidRadius * 100
>           : androidRadius
>         : showMore === 1
>         ? iosRadius * 2
>         : showMore === 2
>         ? iosRadius * 4
>         : showMore === 3
>         ? iosRadius * 10
>         : showMore === 4
>         ? iosRadius * 25
>         : showMore === 5
>         ? iosRadius * 50
>         : showMore === 6
>         ? iosRadius * 100
>         : iosRadius,
> ```

Comment: You could try making a map of `showMore -> androidRadius`.  I doubt it will be fewer lines of code, though.

Comment: `radius: [0, 2, 4, 10, 25, 50, 100] [showMore] * (Platform.OS === 'android' ? androidRadius : iosRadius)` looks like it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite easy to clean this kind of condition using mapping, for instance:

```js
const radiusMap = {1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 10, 4: 25, 5: 50, 6: 100};
const platformRadius = Platform.OS === 'android' ? androidRadius: iosRadius;

// finally,
return { radius: radiusMap[platformRadius] || platformRadius };
```

This will take the radius from the radius map, also returning a default radius if no radius in the map is found.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use object lookups for these situations. So, for `showMore` cases, you can do this: -

```
function getRadius(deviceRadius, showMoreValue){
    const showMoreCases = {
        1: deviceRadius * 2,
        2: deviceRadius * 4,
        3: deviceRadius * 10,
        4: deviceRadius * 25,
        5: deviceRadius * 50,
        6: deviceRadius * 100,
    }

    return showMoreCases[showMoreValue] || deviceRadius;
}
```

And you can use it in the first condition like this: -

```
radius: Platform.OS === 'android'
        ? getRadius(androidRadius, showMore) 
        : getRadius(iosRadius, showMore)
```